# Проблемы с очисткой динамической памяти

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
 main()
{
 int i, aSize;
 int * randomNums;
 time_t t;
 double total = 0;
 int biggest, smallest;
 float average;
 srand(time(&t));
 printf("Сколько случайных чисел будет в массиве? ");
 scanf(" %d", &aSize);
randomNums = (int *) malloc(aSize * sizeof(int));
  // Проверка правильности выделения массива
 if (!randomNums)
  {
 printf("Ошибка выделения массива случайных 
 чисел!\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 // Проход по элементам массива и присвоение 
//каждому элементу
  // целого числа в диапазоне от 1 до 500
  for (i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
 {
 randomNums[i] = (rand() % 500) + 1;
 }
  // Инициализация самого большого и самого
 // маленького числа для последующего сравнения
  biggest = 0;
  smallest = 500;
   // Проход по заполненному массиву и поиск
 // наибольшего и наименьшего чисел, а также
 // сложение всех чисел и вычисление среднего
 for (i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
 {
 total += randomNums[i];
 if (randomNums[i] > biggest)
 {
 biggest = randomNums[i];
 }
 if (randomNums[i] < smallest)
 {
 smallest = randomNums[i];
 }
 }
average = ((float)total)/((float)aSize);
 printf("Наибольшее случайное число: %d.\n", 
  biggest);
 printf("Наименьшее случайное число: %d.\n", 
smallest);
 printf("Среднее из случайных чисел: %.2f.\n", 
average);
 // При использовании malloc, не забудьте 
//   использовать free
 free(randomNums);
 return(0);
}
```

Не могу понять, я же должен освободить память во всех ячейках ? Почему в строчке  free(randomNums) я освобождаю только нулевую ячейку памяти? Если бы не книга , то с помощью цикла я бы прошёлся по каждой ячейке и очистил ее. RandonNums же указатель на массив этих ячеек памяти, или я что-то напутал?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «я освобождаю только нулевую ячейку памяти» — почему вы так решили? За указателем `randomNums` закреплён кусок памяти указанного вами размера, и при вызове `free` освобождается весь этот кусок

Comment: @andreymal, вот, добавил фото объяснения из книжки.

Comment: В книжке как раз изображены те самые куски, о которых я написал, ага. Только на картинке таких кусков пятьдесят (для краткости нарисованы всего четыре), а у вас в коде кусок один-единственный `randomNums`

Comment: Что-то вообще не могу понять, этот кусок же массив

Comment: У вас в коде просто массив, а на картинке в книжке нарисован массив массивов

Comment: Ну так массив это же по сути n-ое кол во переменных, расположенных в памяти рядом.

Comment: Да, и массив это один кусок, на который указывает один указатель, который надо освобождать одним-единственным free.

Comment: Вот так будет выглядеть картинка из книжки, перерисованная под ваш случай: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpdgM.jpg

Comment: Ну вот, нужно же очистить все ячейки

Comment: @andreymal , извините за долгий игнор, произошла экстренная ситуация:)

Comment: Кусок невозможно освобождать по частям, он освобождается весь сразу целиком одним-единственным free

Comment: Хорошо, буду разбираться, спасибо вам:)

Comment: @andreymal ,подождите , но на вашем рисунке же указатель хранит адрес первой ячейки, просто я же написав free(temps), должен освободить первую ячейку динамической памяти. Или это функция free за меня все эти кучи памяти освобождает?

Comment: Ещё раз: куча у вас ровно одна, указатель привязан ко всему этому куску, этот весь кусок освобождается целиком и его невозможно освободить по частям

Comment: Функция `free(ptr)` освобождает ровно столько памяти, сколько было выделено `ptr = malloc(...)`. Функция `free` всегда освобождает непрерывный *блок* памяти, не какую-то "ячейку", о которой вы постоянно твердите.

Comment: @AnT,  ну вот же, указатель хранит адрес массива , который указывает на первый элемент. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpdgM.jpg

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич а менеджер памяти хранит в себе всю длину этого блока памяти и будет освобождать весь этот блок

Comment: Fucking c language, пойду на ютабе пересматривать ролики по этой теме

Comment: Но вам большое спасибо )

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, может быть прочесть [man malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) будет полезней, чем смотреть ролики (сделанные не известно кем)?

Comment: C тут ни при чём. Вам надо понять, как работает микропроцессор и компьютер в общем представлении.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94895/discussion-on-question-by-------).